# SELECT a column from a mySQL table and check validation

Tags: mysql, select, jdbc

I have a mySQL table named userinfo with colums- userId, userName, Password, city, age- userId is Pkey and Autoincremnt

When a user Login on a login.jsp, he submits username and Pasword.

These two parameters of login.jsp are received in UserLogin servlet and then checked in userinfo Table. If matched, he could log in.

I tried SELECT but I get numerous error. What should be the correct way:-

```
try {           

         String sql = "Select UserName, UserPW From  SocialNetwork.RegisteredUser";

           conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();

           PreparedStatement ptmt = (PreparedStatement) conn
                    .prepareStatement(sql);

         ptmt.executeQuery();

         Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        s = connection.prepareStatement("select id_usuario, id_grupo from usuarios_grupos where id_grupo = ?");

            //storing user data in ResultSet
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


            while (rs.next())  {
            String refName = rs.getString("UserName");

            String refPass = rs.getString("UserPW");

            if (user.equals(refName) && pw.equals(refPass) ) {
                out.println("<html>");
                out.println("<body>");
                out.println("You are In");
                out.println("</body>");
                out.println("</html>");

                System.out.println("sucess");   


            }


           }
     }catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What **numerous errors** you got ?

Comment: why r u firing two times query?

Answer (score 0):

by using `Statement`  interface you can not dynamically set the values. use `PreparedStatement` interface for second query.

import package in you class    `import javas.sql.*;`

```
try {           

         String sql = "Select UserName, UserPW From  SocialNetwork.RegisteredUser UserName = ?";
         conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement ptmt =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
           ptmt.setString(1, user)
          ResultSet rs= ptmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next())  {
            String refName = rs.getString(1);//field index of user name
            String refPass = rs.getString(2);//field index of password

            if (user.equals(refName) && pw.equals(refPass) ) {
                out.println("<html>");
                out.println("<body>");
                out.println("You are In");
                out.println("</body>");
                out.println("</html>");
                System.out.println("sucess");   
            }
       }
     }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: when I run this `String sql = "SELECT UserName, UserPW From  SocialNetwork.RegisteredUser WHERE UserName = ?";`
             I get syntex error `for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1`

Comment: so remove that  ptmt.setString(1, user) and use this query.   String sql = "SELECT UserName, UserPW From SocialNetwork.RegisteredUser WHERE UserName ='"+user+"'";

Answer (score -1):

Are you asking for the entire code listing? in your current code you seem to be executing some queries for no reason, then getting a list of all users and iterating through them looking for a match. Try using a query like

```
sql ="Select UserName, UserPW From  SocialNetwork.RegisteredUser where UserName=?"
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

then check the password in code

```
if(rs.next()){
  String refPass = rs.getString("UserPW");
  if (pw.equals(refPass) )
}
```